# Oracle SQL - Execution order or OR / AND conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I get the wrong results when executing a query, but the wrong rows that I get depend of the order of execution. Explanation: if I first execute the Query as follows:

```
select * 
from PROG_TSUJETO_ATRIB_VIG sujetoatri0_ 
where ((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'COM2' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('01/01/2001 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('01/01/2049 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    or((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'COM1' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('01/01/2001 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('01/01/2049 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    or((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'Suje' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('06/06/2015 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('06/06/2015 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    or((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'Suj' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('28/05/2015 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('03/06/2015 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    or((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'CSA.1' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('19/08/2013 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('20/08/2010 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    and(sujetoatri0_.IDN_PARM_ATRIBUTO=55 )and(sujetoatri0_.FECHA_BAJA_LOGICA is NULL )
```

The results I get are:

```
IDN_SUJETO_ATRIB_VIG    FEC_INI_VIGENCIA    IDN_SUJETO  FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA    VALOR   IDN_PARM_ATRIBUTO   SIOMAUD_USUARIO_ALTA    
1   2000-10-10 00:00:00 2   2050-10-10 00:00:00 COM2    55  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
2   2000-10-10 00:00:00 1   2050-10-10 00:00:00 COM1    55  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
541 2015-06-06 00:00:00 1245    2015-06-10 00:00:00 Suje    57  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
544 2015-05-28 00:00:00 1246    2015-06-03 00:00:00 Suj 57  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

I shouldn't get the lines 3 and 4, because I'm asking for 55 and those have 57. But even more, if I change the order of the OR conditions (3rd and 5th), as follows:

```
select *
from PROG_TSUJETO_ATRIB_VIG sujetoatri0_ 
where ((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'COM2' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('01/01/2001 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('01/01/2049 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    or((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'COM1' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('01/01/2001 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('01/01/2049 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    or((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'CSA.1' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('19/08/2013 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('20/08/2010 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    or((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'Suje' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('06/06/2015 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('06/06/2015 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    or((sujetoatri0_.valor like 'Suj' )and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA<=to_date('28/05/2015 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))and(sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA>=to_date('03/06/2015 00:00:00' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')))
    and(sujetoatri0_.IDN_PARM_ATRIBUTO=55 )and(sujetoatri0_.FECHA_BAJA_LOGICA is NULL )
```

The results fetched are:

```
IDN_SUJETO_ATRIB_VIG    FEC_INI_VIGENCIA    IDN_SUJETO  FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA    VALOR   IDN_PARM_ATRIBUTO   SIOMAUD_USUARIO_ALTA    SIOMAUD_FECHA_ALTA  SIOMAUD_USUARIO_ULT_MODIF   SIOMAUD_FECHA_ULT_MODIF SIOMAUD_FECHA_BAJA  FECHA_BAJA_LOGICA
1   2000-10-10 00:00:00 2   2050-10-10 00:00:00 COM2    55  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
2   2000-10-10 00:00:00 1   2050-10-10 00:00:00 COM1    55  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
337 2011-06-01 00:00:00 1142    2011-06-30 00:00:00 CSA.1   57  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
541 2015-06-06 00:00:00 1245    2015-06-10 00:00:00 Suje    57  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

That is, it is ruling out only the LAST wrong condition.
Does anybody have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

AND has a higher precendence than OR - so `a AND b OR c AND d` is actually `(a AND b) OR (c AND d)` similarly, `A OR b OR c AND d` is actually `A OR b OR (c AND d)`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm).  Check your bracketing!

Comment: So that's it, AND has a higher precedence than OR. Didn't know that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From your first query, I have copied, but re-formatted for readability.  Your issue is that all of your "OR" conditions are at the same level as your final "AND" conditions making them qualify.

```
select 
      * 
   from 
      PROG_TSUJETO_ATRIB_VIG sujetoatri0_ 
   where 
         (     ( sujetoatri0_.valor like 'COM2' )
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA <= to_date('01/01/2001 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS' ))
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA >= to_date('01/01/2049 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS' ))
         )
      or (     ( sujetoatri0_.valor like 'COM1' )
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA <= to_date('01/01/2001 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA >= to_date('01/01/2049 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))
         )
      or (     (  sujetoatri0_.valor like 'Suje' )
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA <= to_date('06/06/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA >= to_date('06/06/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))
         )
      or (     ( sujetoatri0_.valor like 'Suj' )
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA <= to_date('28/05/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA >= to_date('03/06/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))
         )
      or (     ( sujetoatri0_.valor like 'CSA.1' )
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_INI_VIGENCIA <= to_date('19/08/2013 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))
           and ( sujetoatri0_.FEC_FIN_VIGENCIA >= to_date('20/08/2010 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))
         )
     and ( sujetoatri0_.IDN_PARM_ATRIBUTO=55 )
     and ( sujetoatri0_.FECHA_BAJA_LOGICA is NULL )
```

I think what you really want is...

```
where (     ( or condition 1)
         OR ( or condition 2)
         OR ( or condition 3)
         OR ( or condition 4)
      )
      AND ( your 55 condition )
      AND ( your null condition )
```

So, by wrapping all your OR conditions as one, it changes the statement to

```
select where ( any of these or conditions )
         AND ( 55 condition )
         AND ( null condition )
```

Per your comment back, the answer is more as Will described, what your query is being interpreted as is PROCESSED as

```
   ( com2 test )
OR ( com1 test )
OR ( suje test )
OR ( suj test )
OR (( CSA.1 test ) AND ( 55 test ) AND ( null test ))
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want but the problem is that I can't seem to be able to insert the parenthesis that I need with our implementation of JPA, but that's another issue. I just wanted to know why it behaves the way it does. Thank you.

Comment: @LuisSep, see revised answer